# Setting multiple if else condition decision-state id in Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am working on existing Spring Webflow application. I set a variable in a sub flow and I want to use decision state to determine the action class. The application already has decision state id specified

```
<decision-state id="condition1">
        <if test="flowScope.conditionCheck1 || flowScope.conditionCheck2" then="action1" else="action2"/>
</decision-state>
```

Now I want to test if condition3 holds true and in case it is true I want to execute action3. Does any one has any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write if else condition i wrote multiple if conditions inside "decision-state-id" and else condition was written in the last if condition and it worked fine for me.

```
<decision-state id="condition1">
    <if test="flowScope.conditionCheck1 || flowScope.conditionCheck2" then="action1"/>
    <if test="flowScope.conditionCheck3 then="action3" else="action2"/>
</decision-state>
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

split your conditions and decision state like this:

```
<decision-state id="condition1">
    <if test="flowScope.conditionCheck3" then="action3" else="condition1or2"/>
</decision-state>
<decision-state id="condition1or2">
    <if test="flowScope.conditionCheck1 || flowScope.conditionCheck1" then="action1" else="action2"/>
</decision-state>
```

Comment: I was trying to specify condition with in the same decision state .

Answer (score 0):

conditions are checked by order.
these worked for me.

```
  <decision-state id="">
        <if test="x == 'a' then="r1" />
        <if test="x == 'b' then="r2" else="r3" />
    </decision-state>
```